# Autoscaler storageclient error

Tags: azure

I get a storageclient dll missmatch error(randomly, not always) while setting up Autoscaler. This problem occured after caching preview incorporation (replacing appfabric caching). binding redirect is in place still I get this error once in a while. There is one way to solve it. remove dll and add it from the same location again!! but doing that every time autoscaler fails is impossible

Comment: When you say Autoscaler do you mean Windows Azure Autoscaling Application Block (WASABi)?

Comment: Assembly is  Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.Autoscaling.dll, v4.0.30319

Answer (score 0):

I have recently see exact same error with other partners. What we did there is CLEAN install [Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0 Integration Pack for Windows Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28189) in your machine and add as reference after the application was updated to use Preview Cache features. As you mentioned you had issue after got your caching updated trying doing the same and hopefully the problem will be resolved.